# How can I highlight in visual block mode all text between two delimiters over multiple lines?

Tags: visual-mode, visual-block

I have a tab-separated spreadsheet and I'd like to highlight in visual block mode by selecting a character, expanding the visual highlight region to the whole entry between the two tab characters, then navigating downwards so that on each further line down the selection is what is between the nearest two tab characters on each line. How might this be possible?

Comment: Block mode only allows selection of a rectangular block of text (unless you're extending to the end of each line in which case the right side can be non-straight). Unless each "cell" in the column has the same width visual block mode won't do what you want.

Comment: What do you _really_ want to do with that selection? There may be a better or different way